# „Night soil“ deutscher Euphemismus gesucht

Tags: translation, history

Es gibt im Englischen für Fäkaldünger den Ausdruck „*[Night soil“](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_soil)*, dem sogar eine eigene Wikipediaseite ohne deutsche Version gewidmet ist. Gesucht ist ein deutscher Euphemismus mit der selben Bedeutung. Idealerweise ein aus dem Mittelalter stammender.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt im Deutschen den Begriff

> [Goldeimer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldeimer)

bei dem es nicht so sehr um die "Produktion" in der Nacht ging, allerdings um das "vergolden" von Fäkalien zu verkaufbarem Dünger. Der *Goldeimer* ist allso der Sammelbehälter für das, was "zu Gold werden" soll.

Dieser Begriff stammt allerdings nicht aus dem Mittelalter, sondern aus dem frühen 20. Jahrhundert. Es war in Deutschland (zumindestens dort, wo genug tierischer Mist vorhanden war) nie besonders üblich, mit menschlichen Fäkalien zu düngen - An sich war ohne eine halbwegs industrielle Aufbereitung einfach die Seuchengefahr viel zu hoch.

Einen mittelalterlichen Begriff finde ich nur für das Klo an sich - In den mittelalterlichen Deutschordensburgen im Osten nannteman die Toilettenanlage den

> [Dansker](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dansker)

(wohl, weil man das erste entsprechende Klo in Danzig gesehen hatte)

Ein eher "kleiner" Euphemismus ist wohl der

> Nachttopf

und auch der (moderne) Begriff

> Braunwasser

ist sicher so einer.

Wenn du einen mittelalterlichen Begriff suchst, dann ist der [Erfurter Latrinensturz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erfurter_Latrinensturz) sicher eine ergiebige Quelle (was es nicht alles gibt...).

Answer (score 1):

Als Übersetzung des französischen (zumindest 1863 in einem deutschen Text verwendeten)

> [Poudrette](http://dingler.culture.hu-berlin.de/article/pj170/mi170mi04_17)

wird

> [Staubdünger](https://www.wissen.de/fremdwort/poudrette)

genannt.

Ersteres steht auch im Fremdwörterduden 1997:

[image]

Euphemismus-Kandidaten sind ferner:

> - [Adel](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Adel_Mistjauche) *(Mistjauche)*, auch unterwegs als:
> - [Odel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odel) *(regionaler Ausdruck für Wirtschaftsdünger aus
>     Urin und Kot)*